# Which formats can Google Docs import/restore?

Tags: google-docs, export, import

I want to export/download files FROM Google Docs in a format that will allow me to import/upload them to Google Docs retaining all possible formatting.

While Google Docs offers several formats to export content in, each of these ends up losing formatting when I try importing them.

Which format(s) should I use, or how can I export documents from Google Docs in order that when I upload them later they will retain their formatting?

Comment: Plain text doesn't have formatting such as you note, it is "plain text". There's nothing to preserve because there was never any of that stuff there. What have you tried? What research have you done?

Comment: @music2myear My point precisely. If you have formatting in the document, the formatting will be lost when you download it as plain text. Yes, I've tried that, I've tried downloading the other formats, looked for an option to import them, ran Google searches that found no mention of such an option.

Comment: I have edited your question substantially to present the question I believe you are actually asking. Because this is no longer SuperUser, the edit has gone into queue and once approved, will show. If you were to explain WHY you believe you need to export/import, and what the root issue is that you're trying to solve, people may have better solutions to offer you.